# Is there a way to prevent apps from disappearing after clicking on a different app?

Tags: applications, google-chrome, notes.app, multitasking

I have an issue with my MacOS where if I have two apps say chrome and notes, and I try to click on the chrome app the notes app would disappear and go into the background. Is there a way to prevent the notes app from going into the background?

I should note that the apps only disappear into the background when using it with the chrome app, so apps like notes and mail mail work in that they don't disappear into the background when one is click

I'm pretty sure this is a feature either with MacOS or chrome since it happens on my other macbook too.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Yes, this is standard behavior in macOS: the active app becomes the frontmost app, possibly hiding other apps. You could try Split View as explained here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948

Comment: The other apps should not 'disappear': their windows should still be visible, but just not 'at the front'. If the app's windows are disappearing, then something odd is happening. That behaviour normally only happens if you hold down ALT when clicking on a window. If it's just happening with Chrome - is it moving to a separate Display Space? ("Desktop")